# Url rewriting stops working after changing default port on iis7

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, migration

I have migrated the IIS6 webserver 2003 websites to IIS7 webserver 2008 using msdeploy tool. Application pool setting are changed with `"Enable 32-bit Applications=true", "Managed_Pipeline_Mode=Classic","Identity=NetworkService" Framework=v1.1/2.0`.

All the websites are working fine on default port along with url rewriting migrated from iis6. When I start the webserver on port other than default port by changing bindings, url rewriting stops workings and get 404 error in logs. I think I don't have to change the handler mapping cause I am running it in classic mode. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: You can start by showing us your rewrite rules

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sorry for my late reply. My web development team said that url rewriting rules are written in the codes and so they are looking into the codes to add the port information for url rewriting. I am waiting for their revert on this. I'll be able to put more information once I get the clear idea hot url rewriting was done in iis6 by the team.

Answer (score 2):

1. Maybe silly, but I will ask anyway, did you restart IIS service?
2. When you switch your website to listening on a non standard port, the port number become part of your **base URL** like following

   ```
   http://example.com:9000
   ```

   Webapp or site config may have to be updated to match that.
3. Rewrite rules involving base url may have to be updated.